# SFTP video stream

Tags: swift, avplayer

Is it posible to do video stream to `AVPlayer` with a private sFTP ?

```
url = URL(string: "sftp://account:pass@host/movie.mov")
if let movieURL = url {
  destination.player = AVPlayer(url: movieURL)
}
```

Comment: Nothing happens, the avplayer is gray and the play button is crossed out

Comment: I improved your code formatting slightly, tags should be used to inform others of what the question is about not what it contains e.g. the FTP tag here is non relevant since it is only used to log in. I added the AVPlayer tag since that is more in the core of your question. Do you have an error you could put in the post?